# Delete all files and folders EXCEPT those with extension .svn and .svn-base

Tags: windows-vista, cmd.exe

I need to remove all files and folders from a particular parent folder except those which have .svn as the foldername and those which have *.svn-base as their filename.

Is there a Windows script that can do this for me?

---

Edit1

@Mizo - your solution returned the following while wiping out everything:

```
C:\temp>clean-all-except-svn.bat
File not found - *.svn_base
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
```

I had changed the clean.bat reference in the file itself.

---

Edit2

I fixed the typo as follows but still the same error

```
XCOPY /Q /Y *.svn-base __cltmp


C:\temp>clean-all-except-svn.bat
File not found - *.svn-base
0 File(s) copied
0 File(s) copied
```

---

Edit3

(a) It keeps prompting me

```
Confirm
The item at C:\temp\f\a\d has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue,
all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

(b) It displays THOUSANDS of messages like:

```
At line:1 char:86
+ get-childitem C:\temp\ -exclude *.svn-base,".svn" -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item <<<<  $_.fullname}
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (change_email.php.svn-base:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\temp\admin\.svn\text-base\change_email_submit.php.svn-base: Not Enough permission to
 perform operation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Powershell:

```
get-childitem C:\folder\ -exclude *.svn-base,".svn" -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

**Update**: the code below should do what you wanted. It removes all files except *.svn-base AND does not delete ANY folders.

Some notes:`gci` is an alias of `get-childitem`, just to save some space. Added `-Force` parameter to `remove-item` since you seem to have some kind of permissions problem.

```
gci C:\folder\ -exclude *.svn-base -recurse | foreach ($_) {if(!$_.PSIsContainer){remove-item -Force $_.fullname}}
```

Comment: @Siim - I didnt realize I had powershell installed. I am trying this solution and it does seem to be working, but it seems to be taking _longer_ than operating through the Windows explorer interface!! (see Edit3 as well)

Comment: @Siim - one problem (which I see I didnt specify the question correctly) is that your solution removes folders as well. I actually do not need any subfolders removed, whether they are .svn or otherwise. How can I modify this script to do that?

Comment: @matt_tm I've updated the code, pls check

Comment: @Siim - I ended up using a variation of the concept - get-childitem C:\temp\ -exclude *.svn-base,".svn" -recurse | foreach ($_) { if ($_.Attributes -ne "Directory") {remove-item -Force $_.fullname} }

Comment: @Siim - thank you for introducing me to the concept of powershell! Wasn't aware of it before!

Comment: @matt_tm Cool, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

**clean.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%d IN ('dir /B /AD') DO IF NOT %%d==.svn RMDIR /S /Q %%d
MD __cltmp
XCOPY /Q /Y *.svn_base __cltmp
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('dir /B /A-D') DO IF NOT %%f==clean.bat DEL /F /Q %%f
XCOPY /Q /Y __cltmp\* .
RMDIR /S /Q __cltmp
```

Comment: @mizo - please see edit1

Comment: @mizo - please see edit2 as well

Comment: @mizo - Issue1: this doesn't get into subfolders at all!

Comment: @matt_tm, no, it wipes out all subfolders whose name is not `.svn`. Do you need it to be recursive?

Comment: Issue2: The first FOR /F statement matches .svn folders anyway... I want to exclude all data which is within a .svn folder!

Comment: @mizo - yes for it being recursive